# Veracrypt - Save password on my personal computer

Tags: hard-drive, encryption, passwords, veracrypt

Noob question guys. I bought an external drive so I can save my personal information like my id, my resume, my contracts my projects, etc....

I encrypted the drive using veracrypt and a password since day one, no keyfiles. However I don't see any option to save my password on my personal computer.

Entering my password on my PC I use every day is meaningless. What I am trying to achieve is:

1. Encrypt my external disk using a password.
2. Save said password on my PC.
3. I don't want to use a keyfile because:

   a. I want to be able to use my drive on a friend's computer without having the keyfile
   with me or by saving the keyfile/password on his computer.

   b. if the hard disk on my PC gets damaged I will lose the keyfile and access to my
   external drive files.

Is what I am describing possible?

FYI: For anybody having the same problem, the feature I am looking for is currently not offered on VeraCrypt. In case you are ok with using non FOSS software, Microsoft's Bitlocker can save your password on your computer.

Comment: You could user whatever you like to save that password, for example a password manager or a simple text document.

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://www.veracrypt.fr/en/Main%20Program%20Window.html), section "Auto-Mount Devices", entering an empty password will check cached passwords. There is similar advice for holding down the Shift key when clicking Auto-Mount Devices.

Comment: what is your OS?

Comment: @FrankThomas Windows 11 Pro